# Application Logging user off after being idle 10 mintues

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, timeout, forms-authentication

I am doing a group project with 4 other people. We are designing a job kiosk in ASP.NET in MVC4 with embedded c# and Razor. It generates dynamic web pages from a server. We are using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 in a Windows 7 environment.

I am working on having the system log the user out if they are idle for 10 minutes. I need some help on how to start coding a way for the system to log the user out. I am basically coding a controller with editing the views(web pages) that the other members in my group have done. This way the timer starts on all the view pages.

Comment: You'd probably be better of saving a last activity `DateTime` stamp and define an activity timeout as `TimeSpan` globally. On every authorization you update the last activity unless he is outside the time window, if the user is timed out you can define him as logged out. This prevents the need for (imo dirty) timers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would typically set the expiration value on the FormsAuthentication ticket, using a sliding window.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" protection="All" 
      timeout="10" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

If you're using the default `[Authorize]` attribute of MVC, and using WebSecurity then this should automatically work.  If you're issuing your own forms authentication ticket, then you may have to set the values explicitly.

Others have mentioned the Session timeout, but beware of two things.  First, you should never do any kind of authentication related to Session, and second Session timeout and Authentication timeout are two different things, although you may want to keep them synchronized.  That's harder to do with the sliding window though.

Answer (score -1):

You can control the session with the following entry in the Web.config, e.g.:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="2" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: As I wrote above, session state has nothing to do with authentication.